# How to calculate the Aspect Ratio of an Hypercube?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I am constructing an hypercube using a GA an want to optimize its aspect ratio not to have an elongated one.

For information, by construct I mean get the minimal and maximal point needed for its construction. So for example, for the 3D [Ishigami](http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/ishigami.html) function varying from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, it leads to the points $a:[-\pi, -\pi, -\pi]$ and $b:[\pi, \pi, \pi]$. The boundaries of the parameters define it. In this case the ratio is 1 but what about the set: $[-\pi,2,-1]\times[0,3,1.5]$?

From that, I need to compute the aspect ratio. The only reference I was able to get was:

> Smith, W. D.; Wormald, N. C. (1998). "Geometric separator theorems and applications". Proceedings 39th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (Cat. No.98CB36280). p. 232. doi:10.1109/sfcs.1998.743449. ISBN 0-8186-9172-7.

It says:

> The Cube-Volume Aspect Ratio (CVAR) of a compact set is the d-th root of the ratio of the d-volume of the smallest enclosing axes-parallel d-cube, to the set's own d-volume.

But I don't understand what is the *smallest enclosing axes...* and how to compute it. As far as I understand from the publication, a volume based ratio is the way to go so I came up with:

$$\frac{\prod_{i}^n (b_{i}-a_{i})}{\left(\frac{\sum_{i}^n (b_{i}-a_{i})}{n}\right)^n},$$

with $n$ the dimension of the hypercube. This leads to a volume ratio. If the distance between extrema points of the hypercube are close to each other, it will leads to unity.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: This question comes from (http://mathoverflow.net/q/257927) where it has been put "off-topic" and you were advised to present it here in Math SE (you should have mentionned it). I am afraid it is off-topic as well here. 2 things are completely unclear to me: why are you interested in this aspect ratio: is it in order that its representation fits in the best way on the screen ? 2) What is the connection with Ishigami ? (no reference given) ?

Comment: I am interested in the aspect ratio because I don't want to have an elongated hypercube. I am looking at a balance between the components. The [Ishigami](http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/ishigami.html) function serves as an example on my definition of an hypercube using the bounds on the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I better understand your objective.

Comment: You are parsing the definition wrong, it's not about the "smallest enclosing axes". The "smallest enclosing axes-parallel $d$-cube" is the smallest $d$-cube that is axes-parallel and encloses the given set. For your set $[-\pi,\pi]\times[-\pi,\pi]\times[-\pi,\pi]$ the smallest enclosing axes-parallel $3$-cube is the same set $[-\pi,\pi]^3$, so the aspect ratio is $1$.

Comment: I understand that from my example the ratio is 1 as the bounds are "even". But what about: $[-\pi,2,-1]*[0,3,1.5]$ for example? BTW this is a 3D input function not 2D as your comment suggest.

Comment: My mistake about the 2D. I read it wrong

Comment: The usual notation is $[a_0,b_0]\times[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]$, i.e. a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)). Now an enclosing cube has to be at least as big as the largest width, i.e. $\max(b_0-a_0,b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2)$. In your second example that's $\max(\pi,1,2.5)=\pi$, so the aspect ratio is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{\pi^3}{\pi\times1\times2.5}}$. Hopefully you get the idea now.

Comment: Super @Rahul I got the idea. Can you create an answer so I can mark it? What do you think about the formula I proposed?